# Instructions for Complete Removal of the three20 Facebook API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

Previously I added three20 with the install script to my iPhone project.  I no longer want to use it and would like to remove it.  I saw various questions about this, but didn't see a clean cut way to thoroughly remove it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the install script? Why is this more complicated than just unlinking a library/framework?

Comment: `svn revert`/`git-revert`/`cvs update -r`?

Comment: i used the python script ttmodule.py from: http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project  . i think there are some properties that you need to unset too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success removing Three20 by just removing the Three20 libraries from a large project. Once that is done you need to fix up the link errors, substituting your own code for the routines formerly provided by Three20.

You might find it better to create a new project and move the code you want to keep into it. Not only will you benefit from a thorough reexamination of code and probably find a fair bit to improve or discard, you will truly get rid of all three20 artefacts and settings, and you might avoid some bugs that I encountered - like the fact that three20's URL-based navigation system escapes all URLs which may or may not match your own preferred resource naming scheme.

If it's code you just want to make work and leave alone maybe a script would work. If it is code you want to maintain and use it might pay to invest the time in it.